# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery[7] Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i deployed a website and when any post process or authorizing process occur, i am getting this error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery[7]
      An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
 ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {key} was not found in the key ring.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext httpContext)
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
```

I suspect the code order is not correct in Configure or ConfigureServices methods, do you think that is the problem?

Startup Configure and ConfigureServices methods :
ConfigureServices:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));//
            services.AddDI();//custom Startup Collection
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>();
            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
            {

                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

            }).AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityValidator.CustomIdentityValidator>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddAuthentication();
            services.AddDataProtection();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options => options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(5));

           
            services.Configure<EmailOptions>(Configuration);//appsettingstekileri değiştirecek
            services.AddCors(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy("global", cors =>
                {
                    cors.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
                });
            });
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {

                options.Cookie.Name = "SiteName";
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(20);
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                options.LoginPath = "/Home/SignIn";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/AccessDenied";
            });
```

I suspect the code order is not correct in Configure or ConfigureServices methods, do you think that is the problem?

Startup Configure and ConfigureServices methods :
Configure:

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, UserManager<AppUser> userManager, RoleManager<AppRole> roleManager, IWebSiteBussRepository webSiteBussRepository)
        {


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }


            IdentityInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager).Wait();
            IdentityInitializer.StaticPage(webSiteBussRepository).Wait();

            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/StatusCode", "?code={0}"); //en üstte olmalı 404 page 'i için yazdım
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors("global");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                     name: "areas",
                     pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                     );
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                   );
            });



        }
```

Comment: please post your startup .cs code.

Comment: You can configure data protection according to the Microsoft documentation provided on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#data-protection.

Comment: @PritomSarkar sorry for seeing it late, i shared startup.cs above

Comment: @gakowiw386 so you are configured shared data protection.please check your application hosted multiple servers or not. also you can try this ```[HttpPost]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]```